# CMake: get output of some command every build and reconfigure files that depends of this value

Tags: cmake

I want to start some command and store its output into some variable. And then reconfigure input file that depends of this variable.

For instance, I want to get current mercurial revision by running `hg id -i`. Output of this command can be changed between builds. So, I have to run this command every time and store output into some variable.

So, because I have to run this command every build, then `execute_process` is not suitable to me. But `add_custom_command` is not suitable too because it cannot save output of the command into a variable.

Let's suppose that I could (in some way) get output of `hg id -i` and store it into `REVISION` variable. Then I want to regenerate configuration file with version:

```
configure_file(version.cpp.in version.cpp)
```

Contents of `version.cpp.in`

```
volatile const char* revision = "Revision: ${REVISION}";
```

As a workaround I can define `REVISION`, but I want to have revision number in source files.

P.S. Mercurial and revision number here is just an example. So, please don't advise some Mercurial's `keyword` extension and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I use the following solution:

In **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
...
# Versioning
# Try to find hg executable, retrive revision if found and generate version.cpp from template
set(VERSIONING_FILES src/versioning.cmake src/version.cpp.in)
find_program(HG hg DOC "Mercurial executable file")
# invalidate template
add_custom_target(versioning ALL COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/version.cpp.in
    SOURCES ${VERSIONING_FILES})
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/version.cpp
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DVERSION_INPUT=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/version.cpp.in -DVERSION_OUTPUT=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/version.cpp -DHG=${HG} -P ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/versioning.cmake
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/version.cpp.in)
...
```

**src/versioning.cmake**:

```
if (HG)
    execute_process(COMMAND ${HG} id OUTPUT_VARIABLE REVISION OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
else ()
    set(REVISION "<undefined>")
endif ()
configure_file(${VERSION_INPUT} ${VERSION_OUTPUT})
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${VERSION_OUTPUT})    # invalidate output to force rebuild this source file even if it was not changed.

# vim: set ts=4 sw=4 ai tw=0 et syntax=cmake :
```

And contents of the **src/version.cpp.in**:

```
volatile const char* REVISION = "$ Build revision: ${REVISION} $";
volatile const char* ROOT_DIRECTORY = "$ Build directory: ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} $";
volatile const char* BUILD_DATE = "$ Build date: " __DATE__ " " __TIME__ " $";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call `cmake` in scripting mode within `add_custom_target` command:

**configure_version.cmake**:

```
execute_process(COMMAND hg id -i
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE REVISION)
configure_file(${input_file} ${output_file})
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_custom_target(version_target
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
        -Dinput_file=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/version.cpp.in
        -Doutput_file=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version.cpp
        -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/configure_version.cmake
    )
```

The script isn't called within `add_custom_command`, as it is needed to call it every build. Because of that you should add *target-level dependency* (`add_dependencies`) between *consumer* of `version.cpp` file and script's target (`version_target`).

It is needed to pass paths of input and output files for `configure_file` in script, because the script doesn't know `CMAKE_*_DIR` variables. Alternatively, you may configure the script file itself.

Comment: In this case seems like I have to pass all other variables of parent CMake script explicitly to `configure_version.cmake`. I mean in case of I want to use in configuration file not only calculated variables.

Comment: It is good approach to keep `version` file contained only version (or some other build identificator) for the project. Other build-calculated constants can be stored to other files.

Comment: This approach has one downside: Targets which are supposed to build `version.cpp` depend on the command which creates this file but not the file itself! It can happen that the file is updated but the target is not rebuilt! I worked around this by using `add_custom_command` and specifically declaring `version.cpp` as an `OUTPUT`. To run on each build a second `OUTPUT` file can be specified for this command that is never actually generated. It's a bit hacky but records proper dependencies without even requiring `add_dependencies` which is handled implicitly when adding `version.cpp` to a target.